# How can I sort GridView in asp.net with dynamically added custom templatefields?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a template class to be used by GridView and it works fine, but if i enable sorting the column headers do not turn into links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to set the SortExpression property of my templates...